# Why "curl -s" and "curl" give the same result?

Tags: bash, curl

On the command line, if I type

```
curl -s http://httpbin.org/get
```

or

```
curl http://httpbin.org/get
```

I get the same result:

```
{
  "args": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.63.0",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5eb2c764-3e67fbd6113ee4c0e5bccd8a"
  },
  "origin": "109.11.151.178",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

---

But if I use a pipeline to use the result of curl, for example, I type this:

```
curl http://httpbin.org/get | grep -E '\d+'
```

Then I get:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   255  100   255    0     0   1237      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1231
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.63.0",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5eb2c935-af183e03612a957bc5d1b48b"
  "origin": "109.11.151.178",
```

If I used the "-s" option for curl, the result of the pipeline is different:

```
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.63.0",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5eb2c990-5b0d5bb00b3c8aff7acf8d79"
  "origin": "109.11.151.178",
```

After some serach on the Internet, I got to know that "-s" option of curl won't print out the progress meter:

> Silent  or  quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages. 
>   Makes Curl mute. It will still output the data you ask for,
>   potentially even to the termi-
>                 nal/stdout unless you redirect it.

- But where does the "progress meter" come from ?
- Why the "progress meter" doesn't show when I use "curl" or "curl -s" ?
- Why does it occur when a pipeline is used ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man curl`:

> **PROGRESS METER**
>   `curl` normally displays a progress meter during operations, indicating the amount of transferred data, transfer speeds and estimated time left, etc.
>
> [...] if you invoke curl to do an operation and it is about to write data to the terminal, **it disables the progress meter** as otherwise it  would mess up the output mixing progress meter and response data.

Comment: LOL!  Right as I fixed my deleted answer to show this, you beat me to it!  =)  +1